# get the file name that has specific extension in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have three files in a directory that has the structure like this:

```
file.exe.trace, file.exe.trace.functions and file.exe.trace.netlog
```

I want to know how can I get file.exe as file name?
In other world I need to get file name that has the .trace extension? I should note that as you can see all the files has the .trace part.

Answer (score 2):

If `$FILENAME` has the name, the root part can be gotten from `${FILENAME%%.trace*}`

```
for FILENAME in *.trace; do
    echo ${FILENAME%%.trace*}
done
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you also have to throw away the files which are not *exactly* `file.exe.trace`, so OP might need a solution that works inside a `for FILENAME in *.trace*; do`. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes i need it

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `basename`:

```
for f in *.trace; do 
    basename "$f" ".trace"
done
```

**Update:** The previous won't process files with extra extensions besides `.trace` like `.trace.functions`, but the following `sed` will do:

```
sed -r 's_(.*)\.trace.*_\1_' <(ls -c1)
```

You can also use it in a for loop instead:

```
for f in *.trace*; do 
    sed -r 's_(.*)\.trace.*_\1_' <<< "$f"
done
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about this syntax for `basename`.

Comment: Thanks, but the `basename` approach will ignore files like `file.exe.functions`, I improved the answer using `sed` though

Comment: Well, there are a thousand different ways to do this. My enthusiasm was for the specific use of `basename`, not the solution:) Although wouldn't it be safer to use `echo *` instead of `ls -c1` in your middle example?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this particular case replacing `ls -c1` with `echo *` or even with `echo *.trace*` does not work =/

Comment: Sorry, you're right. And your last solution might even work for weird filenames (whitespace, newline), so that's probably best.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for each in *exe*trace* ; do echo $each | awk -F. '{print $1"."$2}' ; done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You could skip piping echo by calling `awk` with `<<<"$each"`.